# Magento class not found error in admin panel

Tags: php, jquery, magento, admin, magento-1.9

I get this error when I try to enter in module in admin panel:

> Fatal error: Class 'Magebuzz_Pricematch_Block_Extendedlabel' not found in /homepages/25/d508996677/htdocs/jsbfurniture/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Abstract.php on line 146

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you removed Magebuzz extension from your code or it's disabled in xml configuration of the module.